# Airflow v2.3.4: Make all tasks in a DAG run at the same time

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

How can a define the parameters for airflow KubernetesPodOperator make all tasks in a DAG run at the same time.

In my image below you can see that some tasks are in grey "scheduled", I want them to run all at the same time green, also make it NOT possible to run the same task more than once at a time.

#### SO

```
task1_today & task1_yesterday: Cannot run together

task1_today, task2_today, ...taskN_today: Should be running ALL together
```

[image]

This is how my DAGs are defined

#### Arguments

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email": ["intelligence@profinda.com"],
    "retries": 2,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(hours=6),
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "image_pull_policy": "Always",
    "max_active_tasks": len(LIST_OF_TASKS),
}
```

#### Kubernetes pod

```
KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace="airflow",
        service_account_name="airflow",
        image=DAG_IMAGE,
        image_pull_secrets=[k8s.V1LocalObjectReference("docker-registry")],
        container_resources=compute_resources,
        env_vars={
            "EXECUTION_DATE": "{{ execution_date }}",
        },
        cmds=["python3", "launcher.py", "-n", spider_name, "-r", "43000"],
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        in_cluster=True,
        name=f"Crawler-{normalised_name}",
        task_id=f"hydra-crawler-{normalised_name}",
        get_logs=True,
        max_active_tis_per_dag=1,  # Previously task_concurrency before Airflow 2.2
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

> task1_today & task1_yesterday: Cannot run together

This constraint should be working with setting `max_active_tis_per_dag` at the task level to 1 as you already have done.

> task1_today, task2_today, ...taskN_today: Should be running ALL together

This constraint relates to parallelism and DAG `max_active_tasks`. Currently 16 tasks are running which is the default. I think the reason is that you provided `max_active_tasks` in your default args instead of directly to the DAG object.

I think if you add it to the dag object like this it should work:

```py
with DAG(..., max_active_tasks=len(LIST_OF_TASKS), ...) as dag:
```

Alternatively you can also change the Airflow config-level setting `max_active_tasks_per_dag` for all DAGs.

There is [this guide listing different scaling parameters](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-scaling-workers#parameter-tuning) that might be helpful. :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try and let you know

Comment: When you talk about adding it to the task object, do you mena both variables? max_active_tis_per_dag, max_active_tasks

Comment: max_active_tis_per_dag is a task parameter, yes, the way you are already doing it in the KPO code you shared. 


max_active_tasks is a dag-level parameter, so you can add it for example after `start_date` in your DAG definition.